# How to diagnose an ImportError that only occurs in a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, python-import, distroless

I'm trying to add the sentencepiece Python module to a python program in a (distroless) Docker container.

However, whenever I run the program, the Python interpreter immediately aborts with

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _sentencepiece
ImportError: cannot import name '_sentencepiece' from 'sentencepiece' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py)
```

After a bit of headscratching, I believe that the real error is that Python can't load the shared object `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentencepiece/_sentencepiece.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

I used `ldd` to get the static dependencies for the shared object and double-checked that the dependencies are in the container, but the error hasn't gone away.

I've tried some other approaches, namely, trying to get `strace` loaded into the container, but it's been very error-prone, and I'm not sure I'm going down the right path.

So -

What should I be investigating instead?